# Link MATLAB TO Anylogic

Tags: java, matlab, anylogic

Can we link optimization algorithm in MATLAB to simulation model in Anylogic automatically?

I want my results in simulation model (Anylogic) go into MATLAB as inputs and outputs of MATLAB go into Anylogic as it's inputs automatically to find the best optimized answers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.